# Combining forms

Tags: forms, 8

I want to have a fixed number of custom entity add forms combined in one large form, on the same page. Submitted through one submit action. Inline entity form is not really suitable for me in this situation.

Is it possible to grab the form through formbuilder for my entity, strip off the submit and validate actions? I can use the result as a template for the multiples I need. My alternative is having to recreate the entity form fields myself in my custom form.

Comment: Entity forms are not a simple forms so I would use JS to submit them all at once.